# I can open a mySql connection, but not a particular db

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am able to open a MySQL server connection like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "$username", "$password")
```

which confirms that the user and password are correct.

However, this doesn't work:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "$username", "$password", "$dbName")
```

It gives me:

```
Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' to database 'yyy'
```

I confirmed that database yyy has user xxx, and that user xxx has full privileges.

What PHP statements can I add after I open the server connection, to help me determine why access is denied?

Comment: please delete the user from mysql -> user table and add again.

Comment: I had already tried that. No difference. Thanks though.

Comment: I just tried creating a brand new user, and a brand new database. Same result.

Comment: can you issue "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" at mysql prompt and test again?

Comment: #1227 - Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation

Comment: I did the "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" through PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die ("Could not connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($con,"test_database") or die ("no database");
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /home/elithi5/public_html/eliflex.php on line 214                     
    no database

Comment: Does that mean that actually, no, I did not connect to the MySQL server?

Comment: I noticed you are using variables for username and password.  Are those actually objects or are they strings?!  Do a var_dump(); of each and let me know what it says.

Comment: They are strings

 echo var_dump($username);
 echo var_dump($password);
 echo var_dump($dbName);
 
 I edited out the actual login info, for obvious reasons
 
 string(14) "...." 
string(14) "..." 
string(15) "elith5_products"